# How to define a brotherhood relationship and write a query that gives every uncle of a person X in the knowledge base An uncle X

Tags: prolog

If u have these facts:

```
parent(albert, bob).
parent(albert, betsy).
parent(albert, bill).

parent(alice, bob).
parent(alice, betsy).
parent(alice, bill).

parent(bob, carl).
parent(bob, charlie).

teacher(albert).
teacher(alice).
```

How to define a brotherhood relationship and write a query that gives every uncle of a person X in the knowledge base. An uncle
is defined as brother of one’s parent.

Comment: Need to add more facts (e.g. using male/1), to prevent alice being considered an uncle.

Comment: You can't define brother, sister, mother, father, aunt, uncle, etc. without knowing gender.

Comment: Possibly OP said 'uncle' but actually means 'sibling of a parent' - if it's a language thing.